# Java frequency analysis performance

Tags: java, audio, fft, frequency, sampling

I'm working on an application that samples audio and needs to do real time processing (FFT and harmonic product spectrum) of this data.

I need to use a sampling rate of 44100Hz and need a frequency resolution of 0.5Hz, meaning I need 88200 samples pre-FFT. This takes about 2 seconds to capture since it's twice the sampling rate; however, after the first sample, I do improve things significantly by using a circular buffer for the sampling and read only half as many samples from then on.

Unfortunately, the performance is still quite low and there is quite a bit of latency. This is a big problem since the application needs to be responding in a timely manner to input as it happens.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I might improve the performance of this? I think the main problem lies in the requirement for large samples and it would be good if there was some way I could reduce how much audio is read while still maintaining the same accuracy. Would threading perhaps help here?

**EDIT**

If it helps to know, I am trying to do real-time F0 estimation from electric guitar input, along with multiple F0 estimation for chord matching. I have methods of doing this that work and are quite accurate, but it's for a uni project and I don't really have enough time left to look too far into other methods than the FFT. Really, I'm just hoping for some kind of way to speed up the sampling process.

Comment: Is it possible to improve the concurrency level? For e.g. split the file into smaller chunks (for a start 2 chunks) and run the sample them under different threads? If you don't have a dependency on hardware (CPU driven and not sound card driven) I think this divide and conquer approach may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to capture 2s of audio initially, this will set a lower bound on latency. Even with your 50% overlap you will still have a minimum latency of 1s. The FFT and other processing will only add to this, but hopefully not by a significant amount (otherwise use a faster FFT library). The only way you will be able to reduce this latency is by sacrificing frequency resolution.

Comment: This is what I feared. I think some people have tried using some kind of interpolation of zeroes with the FFT input to increase the resolution but still using fewer samples. I might try that and see how it works, but I think that alone will not be a solution.

Comment: Padding with zeroes doesn't give you any more *accuracy*, it just interpolates your frequency domain data so that you get more apparent resolution, but this is really just cosmetic - it won't separate peaks that are too close together to resolve based on your sampling rate, i.e. you can't get information from nowhere. It would probably help if you gave a high level idea of what you are trying to do, as there may be other approaches.

Comment: I've edited the question with more info on my project. And as far as zero padding goes, does it make a difference if I'm only interested in a certain frequency range? Also, would averaging the surrounding bins for these interpolated points be something to consider?

Comment: OK - I thought it might be yet another pitch estimation question. ;-) You might want to look at some of the other questions and answers on SO on this subject, as it's been quite extensively covered over the last couple of years - there seem to be an awful lot of people writing guitar tuners and similar apps for iOS etc. An FFT-based approach is probably not ideal, but if you are time-limited then you may just have to make the best of it.

Comment: I was aware that there were other options but, honestly, the FFT approach was the only one I could really understand. I have found that the explanations for these things online are not so great (at least not for someone without an advanced mathematics background). Thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 1):

Using an FFT method gives you a time-frequency trade-off.  If you want lower latency, you will have to use less data, which with an FFT (either shorter or zero-padded) will give you a less accurate frequency estimate.

Zero-padding will just give you a high-quality interpolation. But this may provide a better peak frequency estimate than just using the center of the peak bin of a shorter FFT.